# Functional equation $g(x+y) = g(x)g(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ such that $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141293/continuous-functions-on-mathbb-r-such-that-gxy-gxgy)

Let $g: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function which is not identically zero and which satisfies the functional equation $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$

Suppose $a>0$, show that there exists a unique continuous function satisfying the above, such that $g(1)=a$.

Comment: Uhm - homework?

Comment: Patrova = [Sikhanyiso](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/30677/sikhanyiso)?

Comment: Also, almost verbatim the same question was completely answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/141293/5363).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $g(n)=g(1)^n=a^n$, and $g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=g(1)=a>0$ so that $g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=a^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Putting these together you get that $g(q)=a^q$ for every $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and $a^x$ and $g(x)$ are continuous and agree on $\mathbb{Q}$ they must be equal.