# $\frac{f(t+T)}{f(T)} = f(t)$ then $f$ is an exponential function

Tags: calculus, probability, functional-analysis

If $f$ is a function such that for all $(T, t) \in \mathbb{R}^2_+$ we have : $$\frac{f(t+T)}{f(T)} = f(t)$$

Then how can I prove that $f$ is an exponential function ?

Comment: Start with $a=f(1)$, then show that $f(x)=a^x$

Comment: How are you defining exponential function?

Comment: Please follow [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293371/how-do-i-prove-that-fxfy-fxy-implies-that-fx-ecx-assuming-f-is) link

Comment: It's not true in general unless you make some additional assumption: for example, $f$ differentiable at some point, or $f$ continuous at some point, or $f$ bounded on some interval.

Comment: Echoing @DanielSchepler's remark!

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to prove this function is exponential, you need to explicitly tell that function is differentiable**

Given $$f(t+T)=f(t)f(T)$$

Now take derivative w.r.t. $t$.

$$f'(t+T)=f'(t)f(T)$$

Now put $t=0$, to get

$$f(T)f(0)=f'(T)$$

Let $y=f(T)$ and now solve differential equation.

Comment: This assumes the function is differentiable around 0, but OP only asks for continuous.

Comment: @gt6989b Thanks, I have added that in my answer.

Comment: Actually, continuity is enough, but a different argument is needed.

Comment: Yes, but that is not always easy to assume. There is a proof without that assumption

Comment: @Wojowu If you know, then please add that as an answer, I would like to see that.

Comment: If you assume continuity as one point $c$ then via $f(x + h) = f(x - c)f(c + h)$ we can see that $f$ is continuous everywhere. If $f$ vanishes at one point it vanishes everywhere. So let's assume $f$ to be non-zero and then $f(x) = (f(x/2))^{2} > 0$ so that $f$ is positive. Now integrate $f(x)f(t)=f(x + t)$ between $0$ and $1$ with respect to $t$ and you get $f(x)F(1) = F(x + 1) - F(x)$ where $F(y) = \int_{0}^{y}f(t)\,dt$ and since $F$ is differentiable, $f$ is also differentiable.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh It is awesome, can I add that to my answer?

Comment: You can add in your answer. I have no issues.

Answer (score 3):

You need some smoothness for $f$, i.e., the $f$ is for example continuous, otherwise, using the Axiom of Choice one can define a discontinuous, nowhere bounded $f$ satisfying the condition in the OP, in the same way that one can define a discontinuous $g$ satisfying $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$.

Assume that $f$ is continuous. Then set 
$$
g(x)=1+\int_0^x f(t)\,dt.
$$
Hence $g'=f$ and $g(0)=1.$
Then $g$ is continuously differentiable and
$$
g(x)=1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(kx/n)
=1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \big(f(x/n)\big)^k
=1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{n}\frac{f(x)-1}{f(x/n)-1}
=1+\big(f(x)-1\big)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{f(x/n)-1}{x/n}},
$$
which shows that $f$ is also differentiable.

Ince $f$ is differentiable, obtain 
$$
f'(t)\leftarrow\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}=f(t)\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\to f'(0)f(t)
$$
and hence
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-f'(0)t}\big(f'(t)-f(0)f(t)\big)=0\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\left(\mathrm{e}^{-f'(0)t}f(t)\right)'=0\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \mathrm{e}^{-f'(0)t}f(t)=c\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad f(t)=c\mathrm{e}^{f'(0)t}
$$
But $f(0)=1$ implies that $c=1$ and finally $f(t)=\mathrm{e}^{f'(0)t}$.