# Proving a random variable is an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable, with $$P(X>a+b)=P(X>a)P(X>b)\qquad \forall a,b>0.$$
Prove that $X$ is exponentially distributed.

I know this random variable must have the PDF $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$; how do I prove it given the above?

Comment: Start with h(x)=P(X>x).  Then h(a+b)=h(a)h(b).  let g(x)=log(h(x)).  So g(a+b)=g(a)+g(b).  I suspect that g(x) must have a simple form like g(x)=kx (using continuity).  You should be able to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment

1. From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293371/how-do-i-prove-that-fxfy-fxy-implies-that-fx-ecx-assuming-f-is) you will see that any function that satisfies

$$
f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)
$$

implies that

$$
f(x) = e^{\mu x}
$$

2. Call $f(y) = P(X > y)$ in the expression above, we must then have something like

$$
P(X > y) = e^{\mu y}
$$

But since we require that this number vanishes as we approach infinity, this implies that $\mu$ must be negative, $\mu = -\lambda$, for $\lambda > 0$

$$
P(X > y) = e^{-\lambda y} = \int_y^{\infty}{\rm d}y' f_X(y')
$$

3. Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus you get

$$
f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}
$$