# Solving functional equation $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ under some constraints

Tags: functional-equations

Suppose that $x, y \in \{1,\dots, n\}$. Is it possible to find a nonzero $f \in \mathbb{C}$ such that

$$f(x+y) = f(x)f(y) \text{ for } x \neq y$$

$$f(x)^2 - \frac{1}{2x-1} = f(2x)$$

This problem is related to [solving $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y) $ with solution $a^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293371/how-do-i-prove-that-fxfy-fxy-implies-that-fx-ecx-assuming-f-is).

Comment: Is the function meant to be discrete?

Comment: @Certainlynotadog yes the functions are discrete for finite $n$.

Comment: @WlodAA Why are the conditions contradictory? Notice that the first condition is for when $x \neq y$ and the function is only defined over $\{1, \dots, n\}$.

Comment: KRL, I rushed,  (I missed $\ x\ne y$), I apologize.

Comment: Are $1\ldots n$ integers? What about $\ f(x+y)\ $ when $\ x+y> n?\ $ (the same for $\ 2\cdot x>n).\ $ Is $\ f(k)\ $ arbitrary when $\ k>n?$

Comment: @wlodaa $f(k)$ is not defined when $k>n$.

Comment: Thus the theorem is true for $\ n=1\ $ for the trivial reasons. ==== Also, the theorem is true for $\ n=2.\ $ There are infinitely many solutions, all given by $\ f(2) = f^2(1)-1.\ -$

Comment: Then, for $n=3$, we have every $\ f\ $ such that $\ f(2) = f^2(1)-1\ $ and $\ f(3):=f(1)+f(2).\ $ ==== There are no obstructions so-to-speak. The actual challenge starts at $\ n=4=1+3=2+2.$

Answer (score 0):

There is a trivial solution for $\ n=1\ $ and a simple solution for
$\ n=2.\ $ It is however straightforward to see that there does not exist any solution for any $\ n\ge 4.\ $ I'll leave the pleasure of verifying this to the readers. (*You may consult my comments above, under the OP's Question*).