# Finding all possible distributions of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, density-function

**Question**

Suppose that a random variable $X$ has the property that, for any $a > 1$, the conditional distribution of $\frac 1 a X$ given that $X > a$ is the same as the distribution of $X$. Specify all possible distributions of $X$.

**My thoughts**

I do know that $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = \frac {f_{X, Y}(x,\ y)} {f_Y(y)}$ and I suppose I have to make use of this relationship, but I have no idea how to even begin - When I find conditional distributions, I am usually given a specific value, not something like $X > a$. Any proposed solutions with intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in the question can be written as
$$
\mathsf{P}(X>ax\mid X>a)=\mathsf{P}(X>x),
$$
assuming that $\mathsf{P}(X>a)>0$ for all $a>1$. First, it is clear that $\mathsf{P}(X\le x)=0$ for all $x\le 1$. For $x>1$, the equation becomes (using Bayes' rule):
$$
\mathsf{P}(X>ax)=\mathsf{P}(X>x)\mathsf{P}(X>a),
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\bar{F}(ax)=\bar{F}(x)\bar{F}(a),
$$
where $\bar{F}$ is the complementary cdf of $X$. This is [Cauchy’s power equation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe-toc4.htm), and its solution is given by $\bar{F}(x)=x^c$ for an arbitrary constant $c<0$ ($\because 
\lim_{x\to\infty}\bar{F}(x)=0$).

Comment: 1) The distribution of a random variable is $P_X(A)=\mathsf{P}(X\in A)$, where $A$ is a "nice" set. In particular, $P_X((x,\infty))=\mathsf{P}(X>x)$.

Comment: 2) Given (1), $P_{X/a}((x,\infty))=\mathsf{P}(X/a>x)=\mathsf{P}(X>ax)$.

Comment: 3) When $x<1$, $\{X>a\}\cap \{X>ax\}=\{X>a\}$.

Comment: I see. Actually I was confused because I know that you were considering $P((x, \infty))$, but I could not see why you did not consider $P((-\infty, x))$. Would this be because it was given that $X > a$ and $a > 1$, so we know we are dealing with everything "to the right" of $x$, until $\infty$?

Comment: That's because the resulting equation is "easy" to solve. Try $\le$ instead...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Complementary_cumulative_distribution_function_(tail_distribution)

Comment: For all negative $c$. $1-x^c$ is not a cdf when $c\ge 0$.

Comment: Use Use $\bar{F}(x)=f(\log(x))$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293371/how-do-i-prove-that-fxfy-fxy-implies-that-fx-ecx-assuming-f-is)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I have another query... just to double-check if I am understanding this problem correctly. For $-1 \leq c < 0$, $\mathbb{E}(X)$ does not exist right? However, this does not mean that $c$ cannot take those values right? It just simply means that $\mathbb{E}(X)$ does not exist?

Comment: Yes. The expectations is $\infty$ for $-1\le c<0$.

Comment: I am having difficulty with another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4119326/possible-extension-of-the-concept-of-radially-symmetric-distributions?). If you have some time, do you mind taking a look at it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @EthanMark Google for ""p-spherical distributions"...