# Determine the continuous function such that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{x-a}= e^{a},$ and $(x-a)(y-a)f(x+y)=(x+y-a)f(x)f(y)$

Tags: functions, continuity

Determine the continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

1. $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{x-a}= e^{a},$$ where $a$ is a real valued constant;
2. $$(x-a)(y-a)f(x+y)=(x+y-a)f(x)f(y),$$
   for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

**What I have tried**

First of all, I have discovered the function $f_{1}=(x-a)e^{a}$, that obviously respects all criteria. I have a feeling that this is the only function.

Let's assume that $f_{2}$ is another function that checks all the criteria. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$,
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}\dfrac{f_{1}(x)}{f_{2}(x)}, & x \neq a \\
1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$.

Obviously, $g$ is also continuous. What I am trying to prove is that $g$ is constant. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: A fixed variable is known as a constant. The word you want is continuous instead of continued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rewrite the functional equation as
$$\frac{f(x+y)}{x+y-a}=\frac{f(x)}{x-a}\cdot\frac{f(y)}{y-a}.$$
Define $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x-a}$. Then, the equation becomes $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$. Here, notice that $g$ would be continuous as well, being the product of continuous functions $f(x)$ and $\frac{1}{x-a}$ (you could argue that there could be problems at $x=a$, but they can be fixed). But then, it is a known result that the only continuous functions that satisfy this equation are $g(x)=e^{cx}$. But to satisfy the first condition as well, $c=1$ is needed. Then, $g(x)=e^x$, and $f(x)=(x-a)e^x$. The uniqueness is given by the functional equation which you can see more detailed [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293371/how-do-i-prove-that-fxfy-fxy-implies-that-fx-ecx-assuming-f-is).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: To be more precise, $g$ could also be $0$. But this is excluded by the fact that $g(a) = e^a$ from the given limit.